# Groupby Sum in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

My table as below:

```
DeviceNumber  PayWay  Money

   000001       A       1
   000002       B       2
   000001       A       1
   000001       B       1.2
   000002       A       2.6
```

I want to get the result:

```
   DeviceNumber  Total   A      B
     000001      3.2    2      1.2
     000002      4.6    2.6    2
```

Is there any sql to achieve this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use SUM and CASE like this

```
SELECT DeviceNumber,sum(money) as Total,
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN PayWay='A' THEN Money ELSE 0
        END) as A,
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN PayWay='B' THEN Money ELSE 0
        END) as B
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY DeviceNumber
ORDER BY DeviceNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DeviceNumber,  SUM(CASE WHEN PayWay='A' THEN Money  END) A,
SUM(CASE WHEN PayWay='B' THEN Money END) B,SUM(Money) TOTAL FROM TABLE
GROUP BY DeviceNumber
```

You can try above query.